# Images are not retrieving through EL ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have some images in spring project directory i.e **/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg**  and trying to access them  through EL  **${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg**
but it  give me **:WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/d/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**. i did'nt understand where i done mistake.please help me soneone.

Here is my jsp file

```
[![<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

 <img alt="" src=" <%= request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg") %>">
<img  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg" border="0" 
                title="Download this document"/>

</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

spring configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />


    <context:annotation-config/>
      <beans:bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <beans:property  name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/image?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
   <beans:property  name="password" value="jnk"/>
    <beans:property  name="username" value="root"/>
   </beans:bean>
   <beans:bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bean"/>
   <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
  <beans:props >
  <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
     <!--   <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop> -->
  </beans:props>
  </beans:property>

   </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>


 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

       <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: you can't do this : `<img  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/DOCDB0AD7274B.jpg"`, make some research to find how `<img />` tag works.

Comment: add the resource folder in deployment assembly and put the assets filder in WEB-INF if you are using any ide . then assess like assets/images.... . That should work